# CKEditor - inline: showing up in disabled mode

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

i'm trying to use CKEditor in inline mode like the following:

```
var div = $("div.content");
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
CKEDITOR.inline( div[0]);
```

when clicking the div, the CKEditor toolbar will show up, but all buttons are disabled and i can't edit anything. When using CKEDITOR.replace(..) - i'm getting the normal editor and anything works fine. any ideas what's wrong with the inline setup?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

That element (`div.content`) needs to have a `contenteditable` attribute set to `true`. Without it, it's in normal, read-only mode.

```
var div = $( 'div.content' );
div.attr( 'contenteditable', 'true' );
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
CKEDITOR.inline( div[ 0 ] );
```

Comment: but it still shows the toolbar on clicking the inline editor. can we not show the toolbar also?