# CKEDITOR toolbar not enable

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, inline-editing

I created an inline editor using ck editor using,

```
 CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor1xxx');
```

The editor is showing,But the tools in toolbar was disabled.the elemett editor1xxx is dynamicaly created using javascript.It showing toolbar properly when it invoke on DOM load.but not for dynamically created elements.

[image]

Comment: Which version of CKEditor do you have? Are you able to write in the element? What is the type of the element `div`, `span`, `p`, ... ?  Depending on the type of the element only certain toolbar items are active (those that are valid for the element).

Comment: try  `$('#editor1xxx').attr('contenteditable', true);
 CKEDITOR.inline('editor1xxx');`

make sure that 'editor1xxx' div is visible before setting its contenteditable attribute to true.

Comment: @t.niese, I am using ckeditor 4.3.1,ANd that element is a <div>

Comment: @DeepSharma I tried,But not working.result being the same.Actualy my element have already an attribute contenteditable='true'

Comment: check it in other browsers see if it is working.

Comment: But you can write in the element, even if the control elements are disabled and except that it is disabled the toolbar shows/hides correctly? Was the element invisible/hidden at the time where you call `CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor1xxx');`?

Comment: @t.niese It is not hidden when i call the function

Comment: @DeepSharma ,Yes,In firefox it is working.Only in firefox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761351/ckeditor-inline-showing-up-in-disabled-mode

Comment: @DeepSharma But the resukt was the same